# Syntax error while creating table with foreign key

Tags: sqlite, flutter

Here I am saving details of customer in customerDetails table and languages selected by user in languagesKnown table.

Since languages column has multiple values I decided to create separate table for it.

Can anyone tell how can i do it.

flutter says syntax error

E/SQLiteLog( 5594): (1) near "language": syntax error

I/flutter ( 5594): error DatabaseException(near "language": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE languagesKnown(custId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (custId)REFERENCES customerDetails, language STRING,PRIMARY KEY(custId))) sql 'CREATE TABLE languagesKnown(custId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (custId)REFERENCES customerDetails, language STRING,PRIMARY KEY(custId))' args []} during open, closing...

database_helper.dart

```
await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE customerDetails (custId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
            'custName STRING, '
            'mobileNum STRING, company STRING, custPhoto STRING, showOnCall bool,'
            'remindOn STRING,location STRING)');
await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE languagesKnown(custId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (custId)REFERENCES customerDetails, language STRING,PRIMARY KEY(custId))'
    );
```

database_helper.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:customer/models/model.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

abstract class DB {
  static Database _db;

  static int get _version => 1;

  static Future<Database> init() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }

    try {
      var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
      String _path = p.join(databasesPath, 'Customer.db');
      _db = await openDatabase(_path, version: _version, onCreate: onCreate);
      print('db location:'+_path);

    } catch (ex) {
      print(ex);
    }
  }

  static void onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE userDetails (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
            'firstName STRING, '
            'lastName STRING, mobileNum STRING, emailId STRING, address String,'
            'userType STRING,password STRING)');
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE customerDetails (custId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
            'custName STRING, '
            'mobileNum STRING, company STRING, custPhoto STRING, showOnCall bool,'
            'remindOn STRING,location STRING)');
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE noteDetails (noteId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
            'custId STRING, '
            'custName STRING, date STRING, note STRING, remindOn STRING,'
            'priority STRING,status STRING,attachment STRING)');
    await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE languagesKnown(custId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (custId)REFERENCES customerDetails, language STRING,PRIMARY KEY(custId))'
    );

  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> query(String table) async =>
      _db.query(table);

  static Future<int> insert(String table, Model model) async =>
      await _db.insert(table, model.toMap());

  static Future<int> update(String table, Model model) async => await _db
      .update(table, model.toMap(), where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [model.id]);

  static Future<int> delete(String table, Model model) async =>
      await _db.delete(table, where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [model.id]);

  static Future<int> deleteCustomer(String table, Model model) async =>
      await _db.delete(table, where: 'custId = ?', whereArgs: [model.custId]);

  static Future<Batch> batch() async => _db.batch();

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> rawQuery(String table) async =>
      _db.query(table);


}
```

Comment: Try giving space after languagesKnown  `CREATE TABLE languagesKnown (custId INTEGER ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CREATE TABLE SQL for the **languagesKnown** table needs to be either

```
CREATE TABLE languagesKnown(custId INTEGER REFERENCES customerDetails(custId), language STRING,PRIMARY KEY(custId))
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE languagesKnown(custId INTEGER, language STRING, FOREIGN KEY (custId) REFERENCES customerDetails(custId) PRIMARY KEY(custId));
```

- The first is a column based definition of the Foreign key and only needs the REFERENCES part.
- The 2nd is a table level that uses the full FOREIGN KEY syntax.
- The second (table level) would be required for composite foreign keys.